# What are these extra output lines in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

It's for sometime that these lines can be seen after running a command (randomly):

```
[1]-  Done                    wget -c http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/zorin-os/9/zorin-os-9-core-32.iso?r=http%3A%2F%2Fzorinos.com%2Fdownload9.html
[2]+  Done                    ts=1460659842
```

First line is the command itself & it's not happening always. But from time to time a command line app stops without returning to command line, until I press enter; which shows these lines.

My system did not behave like this until a week ago. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have probably issued a command like this:

```
wget -c http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/zorin-os/9/zorin-os-9-core-32.iso?r=http%3A%2F%2Fzorinos.com%2Fdownload9.html&ts=1460659842&something-else
```

That command contains the special character `&`, which is used to [run multiple processes concurrently](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html). That command is being interpreted as three (or more) commands:

```
# First command (the one that you see after [1]):
wget -c http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/zorin-os/9/zorin-os-9-core-32.iso?r=http%3A%2F%2Fzorinos.com%2Fdownload9.html
# Second command (the one that you see after [2]):
ts=1460659842
# Third command (the one which output should be above the "Done" lines):
something-else
```

Here's an example that may help you understand better:

```
# Here I'm launching three 'echo' commands, the first two in background, the third in foreground
andrea@andrea-laptop:~$ echo first & echo second & echo third
[1] 5033    # This is bash telling me that the first process was started with job number 1 and PID 5033
first       # This is the output from the first process
[2] 5034    # This is bash telling me that the second process was started with job number 2 and PID 5034
third       # This is the output from the third process
second      # This is the output from the second process
andrea@andrea-laptop:~$ 
[1]-  Done                    echo first    # This is bash telling me that the first background job has quit
[2]+  Done                    echo second   # This is bash telling me that the second background job has quit
```

You should properly quote URLs to avoid this and other nasty effects:

```
wget -c 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/zorin-os/9/zorin-os-9-core-32.iso?r=http%3A%2F%2Fzorinos.com%2Fdownload9.html&ts=1460659842&something-else'
```

Comment: Yet another reason why you should never blindly copypaste terminal commands... Someone could make a url http://someurl.com/index.php&malicious-command-here and people would just run it and break their system.